# getaddrinfo() returns error "The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found."

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I am using getaddrinfo in my sample program to translate the host name to address.But it is failing with this error "The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.".

Sample code:

```
struct addrinfo hints, *save_res= 0, *res= 0;
int gai_rc;
char host[] = "localhost";
char port[] = "3333";

/* set hints for getaddrinfo */
ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
hints.ai_protocol= IPPROTO_TCP; /* TCP connections only */
hints.ai_family= AF_UNSPEC;     /* includes: IPv4, IPv6 or hostname */
hints.ai_socktype= SOCK_STREAM;
/* Get the address information for the server using getaddrinfo() */
gai_rc= getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &res);
if (gai_rc != 0)
{
    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d - %s\n", gai_rc, gai_strerrorA(gai_rc));
    return false;
}
printf("success");
```

From MSDN documentation: 
WSANO_DATA
11004
Valid name, no data record of requested type.
The requested name is valid and was found in the database, but it does not have the correct associated data being resolved for. The usual example for this is a host name-to-address translation attempt (using gethostbyname or WSAAsyncGetHostByName) which uses the DNS (Domain Name Server). An MX record is returned but no A record—indicating the host itself exists, but is not directly reachable.

Can someone please suggest why it is giving this error for locahost. I am unable to figure out what is the issue here..

Comment: use perror in place of printf

Comment: @UmerFarooq The `getaddrinfo` function doesn't set `errno`. It has its own error codes.

Comment: I think the error message is pretty descriptive.

Comment: Why are you putting the port in the request? Are you expecting the service to use port 3333? Do you have something in /etc/services for port 3333? Does it work, if you only provide the host parameter and hints?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try to remove the:

```
hints.ai_protocol= IPPROTO_TCP;
```

it will not affect the desired results, since:

```
hints.ai_socktype= SOCK_STREAM;
```

is telling it to choose only tcp connections.
Maybe you can also use only the first, but I didn't checked it.